# Multithreading non-static in class C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, createthread

I am developing an application for Windows in which required run three processes:_thread_EEG (acquisition), _thread_MachineLearning (processing), _thread_Interface (interface). The second process uses data by the first process, and third process requires the result of the second process.

```
class uMotor{
private:
    long _endTime;

    bool _busyBuffer;
    bool _busyLabel;

    Raw  _Shared_buffer;
    char _Shared_label ;

    uEEG _gtec;
    Interface _screen;

    void _EEG            (long endTime);
    void _MachineLearning(long endTime);
    void _Interface      (long endTime);

    DWORD __stdcall _Thread_EEG(LPVOID arg){
        uMotor *yc_ptr = (uMotor*)arg;
        yc_ptr->_EEG(_endTime);
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD __stdcall _Thread_MachineLearning(LPVOID arg){
        uMotor *yc_ptr = (uMotor*)arg;
        yc_ptr->_MachineLearning(_endTime);
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD __stdcall _Thread_Interface(LPVOID arg){
        uMotor *yc_ptr = (uMotor*)arg;
        yc_ptr->_Interface(_endTime);
        return 1;
    }

public:
    uMotor();
    void BCI();
    ~uMotor();
};
```

The threads are called in function `uMotor::BCI()`:

```
void uMotor::BCI(){
    const long NUM_SECONDS_RUNNING = 9;

    long startTime = clock();
    long endTime = startTime + NUM_SECONDS_RUNNING * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    HANDLE Handle_Thread_EEG             = 0;
    HANDLE Handle_Thread_MachineLearning = 0;
    HANDLE Handle_Thread_Interface       = 0;

    Handle_Thread_EEG = CreateThread(NULL, 0, _Thread_EEG, &endTime, 0, NULL);
    Handle_Thread_EEG = CreateThread(NULL, 0, _Thread_MachineLearning, &endTime, 0, NULL);
    Handle_Thread_EEG = CreateThread(NULL, 0, _Thread_Interface, &endTime, 0, NULL);
}
```

In the function `CreateThread`, Visual Studio 2015 shows an error `argument of type "DWORD(_stdcall uMotor::*)(LPVOID arg)" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please extract a minimal example. Also, use C++11 threads, they integrate much better with C++ than `CreateThread()`. Also, it avoids some dangers like the lacking runtime initialization. Lastly, the difference between a plain function and a member function is explained in the C++ FAQ at parashift's.

Comment: Yes especially as you are using VC++ 2015. No need to rely on the dedicated windows thread implementation when you can use the portable standard version.

Comment: I would highly recommend to use `std::thread` instead of the windows native functions.

Comment: To add up to the above, `std::thread` also makes it a lot easier to use non `static` class members as thread functions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please, some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread function must be static, so add `static` before `DWORD __stdcall`...

Also, fourth parameter to `CreateThread` is the routine parameter. You are expecting pointer to `uMotor`, but passing `&endTime` instead. Replace `&endTime` with `this`.

Comment: Thank you!
But now I have another error: `#error directive: WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h> uMotor c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017814/error-windows-h-already-included-mfc-apps-must-not-include-windows-h, second answer

Comment: I've tried the solutions they suggest unsuccessfully. My application is 64 bits. That could be the problem?

Comment: I was wrong. The solution is to add the header `<afx.h>`. Thank you!